# CentOS subdomain not working

Tags: centos, apache-virtualhost, domain

I'm trying to create a subdomain in my CentOS server but it's redirecting to the main domain name

Here is my virtual host

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.co.uk
ServerAlias domain.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/
ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/requests.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/domain.co.uk/">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.co.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.staging.domain.co.uk
ServerAlias staging.domain.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/staging.domain.co.uk/
ErrorLog /var/www/html/staging.domain.co.uk/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/staging.domain.co.uk/requests.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/staging.domain.co.uk/">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.domain.co.uk [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.domain.co.uk
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Note you have a redirect-to-TLS but apparently no `<VirtualHost *:443>` sections? Also, your second `VirtualHost` reads `.80`, not `:80`, is that a copy-and-typo?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Its in a different conf file and i've not included it here. Also the *.80 was a typo sorry!

Comment: Did you restart Apache after creating the virtual host file? Is the virtual host file in a path included in the `httpd.conf`file?

Comment: @cherdt Yes i've restarted the apche and it didn't make any difference. Also yes the virtual host is included in the httpd.conf.